# django rest framework 3.1 - ModelSerializer - multiple update of nested representations

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my ModelSerializer I have a nested ModelSerialier with `many=True`. The question is how to update all nested instances in update method?

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    things = serializers.ThingsSerializer(many=True)


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        things_data = validated_data.pop('things')
        instance = super(ProfileSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        # here i can't access to ids of things as this is read-only field and it isn't passed to validated_data

        return instance
```

Comment: Hi @lofi, did you find out how to do it? I'm just stuck in the same place. I can't access to ids because they don't pass to validated_data. Would it be necessary to create a custom validate method?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, because of the ids are read only it don't pass the validated_data. The only way I managed to get it done (after a few hours...) is by making the id an integerField:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    things = serializers.ThingsSerializer(many=True)
    id = serializers.IntegerField() # Do this for avoid read-only id!


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        things_data = validated_data.pop('things')
        instance = super(ProfileSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        things_id = things_data['id'] # Now this is possible!

        return instance
```